# Spark Scala GroupBy column and sum values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am a newbie in Apache-spark and recently started coding in Scala.

I have a RDD with 4 columns that looks like this:
(Columns 1 - name, 2- title, 3- views, 4 - size)

```
aa    File:Sleeping_lion.jpg 1 8030
aa    Main_Page              1 78261
aa    Special:Statistics     1 20493
aa.b  User:5.34.97.97        1 4749
aa.b  User:80.63.79.2        1 4751
af    Blowback               2 16896
af    Bluff                  2 21442
en    Huntingtown,_Maryland  1 0
```

I want to group based on Column Name and get the sum of Column views.

It should be like this:

```
aa   3
aa.b 2
af   2
en   1
```

I have tried to use `groupByKey` and `reduceByKey` but I am stuck and unable to proceed further.

Comment: Why have you bet on RDD API if _"I am a newbie in Apache-spark and recently started coding in Scala."_? Why not Spark SQL's Dataframe API?

Comment: I have improved my answer below to include two alternatives ways to achive the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, you read the text file, split each line by the separator, map to key value with the appropiate fileds and use countByKey:

```
sc.textFile("path to the text file")
 .map(x => x.split(" ",-1))
 .map(x => (x(0),x(3)))
 .countByKey
```

To complete my answer you can approach the problem using dataframe api ( if this is possible for you depending on spark version), example:

```
val result = df.groupBy("column to Group on").agg(count("column to count on"))
```

another possibility is to use the sql approach:

```
val df = spark.read.csv("csv path")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_table")
val result = sqlContext.sql("select <col to Group on> , count(col to count on) from temp_table Group by <col to Group on>")
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have already have your RDD populated.

```
   //For simplicity, I build RDD this way
      val data = Seq(("aa", "File:Sleeping_lion.jpg", 1, 8030),
          ("aa", "Main_Page", 1, 78261),
          ("aa", "Special:Statistics", 1, 20493),
          ("aa.b", "User:5.34.97.97", 1, 4749),
          ("aa.b", "User:80.63.79.2", 1, 4751),
          ("af", "Blowback", 2, 16896),
          ("af", "Bluff", 2, 21442),
          ("en", "Huntingtown,_Maryland", 1, 0))
```

**Dataframe approach**

```
  val sql = new SQLContext(sc)        
  import sql.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val df = data.toDF("name", "title", "views", "size")      
  df.groupBy($"name").agg(count($"name") as "") show

**Result** 
+----+-----+
|name|count|    
+----+-----+    
|  aa|    3|    
|  af|    2|   
|aa.b|    2|    
|  en|    1|    
+----+-----+
```

**RDD Approach (CountByKey(...))**

```
rdd.keyBy(f => f._1).countByKey().foreach(println(_))
```

**RDD Approach (reduceByKey(...))**

```
rdd.map(f => (f._1, 1)).reduceByKey((accum, curr) => accum + curr).foreach(println(_))
```

If any of this does not solve your problem, pls share where exactely you have strucked.

Comment: When I tried method 2 and 3, I got this 26: error: value _1 is not a member of Array[String]